# React-Toolbox checkboxes inline

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, checkbox, react-toolbox

I'm currently facing a problem with react-toolbox-checkboxes https://github.com/react-toolbox/react-toolbox/tree/dev/components/checkbox while trying to display them inline like this:

[image]

But all I can do is displaying them like this:

[image]

Code looks like this:

```
           <Checkbox
                checked={this.state.checkboxes[0].task}
                label={t('search:instance_template.task')}
                onChange={() => {
                    this.handleCheckboxChange(0, 'task')
                }}
            />
```

Styles like this:

```
input[type="checkbox"]{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

The checkboxes does receive classes and attributes but attributes like "display: inline-block" don't have any effect onto them. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried styling with flex?

Comment: Yes i did. Variations of: 
`style={{display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row'}}`

Comment: `inline-flex` try

Comment: @Hash Looks pretty good. Only a little margin and padding and that's what I wanted. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Reading Purposes] Linking two pages as well that will help on how each style works. [Flexbox](https://www.sitepoint.com/premium/books/html5-css3-for-the-real-world-2nd-edition/preview/flexbox-and-media-queries-a1a98d2), [CSSFlexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

*Sample related to question.*

[image]

Comment: @Nocebo have a great day :)

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comment of @Hash this is the result:

```
        <div id="instanceCheckboxes" style={{display: 'inline-flex', flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                <Checkbox
                    checked={this.state.checkboxes[0].task}
                    label={t('search:instance_template.task')}
                    onChange={() => {
                        this.handleCheckboxChange(0, 'task')
                    }}
                />
                ...
            </div>
```

It wasn't necessary to style the checkboxes directly. That's the result:
[image]